# Using Opera with Robotframework on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, opera

I am facing with trouble to use Opera for web site testing in Robotframework with SeleniumLibrary.
I figured out because the code does not handle correctly the Windows path.
(Default approach on Windows: using \ in path instead of /)

To prove this I was able to manage Opera from python if I replace "\" to "/".

See following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "c:/test2/opera.exe"# path to opera executable
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options)
driver.get("http://www.opera.com")# success
```

I try to achive the same within Robotframework with "Create Webdriver" key

See following code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Verify Opera
    ${options}=     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()       sys
    ${options.binary_location}=     Set Variable    C:/Program Files/Opera/51.0.2830.40/opera.exe
    Create Webdriver    Opera   options=${options}
```

But this approach return with the following error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

Could someone help me, what I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute the robot script with Python 3.x